# Handlebars render all from array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

In my appjs file I am trying to display all article titles in descending order.  This works fine,  the problem is that mongoose returns an array and i'm not sure how to write this in handlebars.

```
var bmtitles = BlogModel.find().select('title date').sort("date", -1);

bmtitles.execFind(function(err, ttles) {
    console.log(ttles);
            var model = {
                    layout:'blog.hbs',
                    BmTitles: ttles,
                };
    //render page
    res.render('blog', model);
});
```

I've tried things like these but none work:

```
{{BmTitles.n.title}}
{{BmTitles.title}}
{{BmTitles}}
```

This is what the ttles variable returns (only two posts for testing)

```
[ { _id: 5011b563a947b943dc32d6f5,
    title: 'Blog title one',
    date: Sun Jan 01 2012 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST) },
  { _id: 5011c155a947b943dc32d6f6,
    title: 'secondpost',
    date: Sat Dec 31 2011 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST) } ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd want to use [`#each` to iterate](http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration) over your array:

> **The `each` block helper**
>
> You can iterate over a list using the built-in `each` helper. Inside the block, you can use `this` to reference the element being iterated over.

So something like this:

```
{{#each BmTitles}}
    <p>{{_id}}: {{title}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vZyHn/

Or you could to it [Mustache-style](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html):

> **Sections**
>
> Sections render blocks of text one or more times, depending on the value of the key in the current context.
>
> A section begins with a pound and ends with a slash. That is, `{{#person}}` begins a "person" section while `{{/person}}` ends it.

So this will also work:

```
{{#BmTitles}}
    <p>{{_id}}: {{title}}</p>
{{/BmTitles}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qyE9b/

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I wanted. I accepted your answer.

Comment: I was using an array of objects and didn't have a parent name for my object this line fixed it for me `t({ BmTitles: ttles })`. I didn't realize it had to be named. Thanks!